How does the parent module change variables based on the value of the submodule in springboot?
All Java applications and Zookeeper services are deployed on the same server (IP: 192.168.0.13). Due to insufficient memory on the server, I had to migrate the app-oa application to a backup server.
However, the development and production environments differ. How can I dynamically change the IP value of zookeeper.connect-string in the bootstrap.yml file of cms-config based on the value of app-oa's spring.profiles.active ?
I've tried accessing spring.profiles.active in cms-config through the Environmentobject to dynamically modify the value of zookeeper.connect-string, but the property value retrieved is null.
I don't want to keep changing the value of the Zookeeper IP due to environment differences. Is there any solution?
app-oa application.yaml

spring.profiles.active: dev ---> bootstrap.yml >> zookeeper.connect-string:localhost

spring.profiles.active: pro---> bootstrap.yml >> zookeeper.connect-string:192.168.0.13

The picture below is the dependency structure of my spring boot project.

The configuration of zookeeper in my cms-config bootstrap.yml


Use a profile specific bootstrap.yml in your project.
